# Identity Server .well-known/openid-configuration using IP Address rather than DNS

Tags: security, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an identity server implementation.

If I navigate to https://daart-qa.sandbox.aimsplatform.com/eds-daas/.well-known/openid-configuration

I receive all of the end points as the server IP address rather than the dns entry.

How to change the configuration so that the dns name is the end point rather than the ip address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you configure `PublicOrigin` properly?

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/options.html#identityserver-options

> PublicOrigin
>
> The origin of this server instance, e.g. https://myorigin.com. If not set, the origin name is inferred from the request.